# How do I use a 4x2 ROM to build a 16x4 ROM?

Tags: memory, rom

I tried solving it but I'm not sure if I got it right

[image: tried solution]

Comment: You appear to have the two outputs on each device connected together. And ROMs don't really need a R/W signal.

Comment: If you don't know you've got it right, you should make some kind of testbench and simulate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The outputs do not appear to be correct.

Each pair of ROMs should have an output to each of Y0, Y1, Y2, and Y3.

The first ROM should have one output to Y0, the other to Y1, the second ROM one output to Y2, the other to Y3, the third would go to Y0 and Y1, fourth to Y2 and Y3, etc.

You also have to make sure that the outputs are high impedance when the ROM is disabled so they don't interfere with each other.